# How to disable a style list in TFontDialog?

Tags: delphi, fonts

How to disable a style list in TFontDialog ?

I want to allow users to choose only font name and size.

Effects like strikeout are already disabled with [''fdEffects''](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option.

Comment: `EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(FontDialog.Handle, cmb2), False);` in `OnShow` of the dialog. 'cmb2' is from 'winapi.dlgs' (font.dlg). Or `ShowWindow(..`

Comment: @sertac One day they will change the dialog......

Comment: @David - Control IDs are documented.

Comment: Yes, it's work. Can you convert your comment to answer to up vote?

Comment: @sertac They are documented for old style file dialogs too.

Comment: @David - Yeah, that would be a problem. Changing them, explorer windows etc. caused a lot of problems for programmers. One could have to choose using the newer interface or the old functionality ...

Comment: @sertac Still, until that happens your approach is sound. And it might never happen.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: `TFontDialog` is a wrapper for the Win32 [`ChooseFont()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646914.aspx) function. That API has not been replaced with a newer API, unlike `TOpenDialog` (`GetOpenFileName()` -> `IFileOpeDialog`) and `TSaveDialog` (`GetSaveFileName()` -> `IFileSaveDialog`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The font common dialog of the API, which the VCL component is a wrapper for, does not provide that functionality. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#_win32_Font_Dialog_Initialization_Flags) for more detail.

You can disable the style listbox yourself in an `OnShow` event handler of the dialog:

```
EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(FontDialog.Handle, cmb2), False);
```

Or hide it entirely like `fdEffects` does to effects checkboxes:

```
ShowWindow(GetDlgItem(FontDialog.Handle, cmb2), SW_HIDE);
```

'cmb2' is defined in 'winapi.dlgs.pas'.

Comment: Both `EnableWindow` and `ShowWindow`works. I use cmb2 for style and cmb5 for charset